# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Nullpointerexception, Inflateexception

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

**Please, i got many errors on my code really i need your help.**

**Errors:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: tools.myapp.app1, PID: 23986
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tools.myapp.app1/tools.myapp.app1.activitys.GreatingCardShowActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58 in tools.myapp.app1:layout/activity_greating_card_show: Binary XML file line #58 in tools.myapp.app1:layout/activity_greating_card_show: Error inflating class tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.StickerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3479)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3651)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58 in tools.myapp.app1:layout/activity_greating_card_show: Binary XML file line #58 in tools.myapp.app1:layout/activity_greating_card_show: Error inflating class tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.StickerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58 in tools.myapp.app1:layout/activity_greating_card_show: Error inflating class tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.StickerView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:856)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:963)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1086)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1128)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1086)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1128)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1086)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:684)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at tools.myapp.app1.activitys.GreatingCardShowActivity.onCreate(GreatingCardShowActivity.java:1001)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8109)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8083)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3452)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3651)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference
    at tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.DrawableSticker.getWidth(DrawableSticker.java:38)
    at tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.DrawableSticker.<init>(DrawableSticker.java:10)
    at tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.BitmapStickerIcon.<init>(BitmapStickerIcon.java:16)
    at tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.StickerView.<init>(StickerView.java:129)
    at tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.StickerView.<init>(StickerView.java:111)
```

**Here: layout/activity_greating_card_show**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_ss">
       
       code......

     **//this is a line #58 that the compiler marked** 
        <tools.myapp.app1.StickerView.StickerView
            android:id="@+id/stickerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Here: GreatingCardShowActivity/onCreate**

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    ImageView imageView;
    float f;
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    **//the compiler select this line #1001**
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_greating_card_show); 
    InterstitialAdHelper instance = InterstitialAdHelper.Companion.getInstance();
    if (instance == null) {
        Intrinsics.throwNpe();
    }
    instance.load(this, this);
    this.activity = this;
    this.assetManager = getAssets();
    this.mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    if (Share.ActivityCardCreate) {
        this.bgposition = getIntent().getStringExtra("bgposition");
        Log.e("val", "onCreate: bg pos-->" + this.bgposition);
    } else {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        this.gretingcatname = intent.getStringExtra("gretingcatname");
        this.pos = intent.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
    }
    initView();
    if (Share.ActivityCardCreate || Share.ActivityGalleryCardCreate) {
        ImageView imageView2 = this.iv_custom_sticker_view;
        if (imageView2 == null) {
            Intrinsics.throwNpe();
        }
        f = 1.0f;
        imageView2.setAlpha(1.0f);
        ImageView imageView3 = this.iv_gc_quotes;
        if (imageView3 == null) {
            Intrinsics.throwNpe();
        }
        imageView3.setAlpha(1.0f);
        imageView = this.iv_ad_frame;
    } else {
        ImageView imageView4 = this.iv_custom_sticker_view;
        if (imageView4 == null) {
            Intrinsics.throwNpe();
        }
        f = 0.5f;
        imageView4.setAlpha(0.5f);
        ImageView imageView5 = this.iv_gc_quotes;
        if (imageView5 == null) {
            Intrinsics.throwNpe();
        }
        imageView5.setAlpha(0.5f);
        imageView = this.iv_ad_frame;
    }
    imageView.setAlpha(f);
    initAction();
    drawables_sticker.clear();
}
```

**Here: class DrawableSticker**

```
public class DrawableSticker extends Sticker {

  private Drawable mDrawable;
**// Below is line #10 the compiler select getWidth() in this line**
  private final Rect mRealBounds = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

public DrawableSticker(Drawable drawable) {
    this.mDrawable = drawable;
    this.a = new Matrix();
}

@Override 
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.concat(this.a);
    this.mDrawable.setBounds(this.mRealBounds);
    this.mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override 
public Drawable getDrawable() {
    return this.mDrawable;
}

@Override 
public int getHeight() {
    return this.mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
}

@Override 
public int getWidth() {
    return this.mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); **//here line #38** 
}

@Override 
public void release() {
    super.release();
    if (this.mDrawable != null) {
        this.mDrawable = null;
    }
}

@Override 
public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    this.mDrawable = drawable;
}
}
```

**This is : class Sticker**
"extended in class DrawableSticker"

```
public abstract class Sticker {

   protected Matrix a;
   protected boolean b;
   private String tag = "";
   private float[] mMatrixValues = new float[9];

private float getMatrixAngle(@NonNull Matrix matrix) {
    return (float) (-(Math.atan2((double) getMatrixValue(matrix, 1), (double) 
getMatrixValue(matrix, 0)) * 57.29577951308232d));
}

private float getMatrixScale(@NonNull Matrix matrix) {
    return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double) getMatrixValue(matrix, 0), 2.0d) + 
Math.pow((double) getMatrixValue(matrix, 3), 2.0d));
}

private float getMatrixValue(@NonNull Matrix matrix, @IntRange(from = 0, to = 9) int i) {
    matrix.getValues(this.mMatrixValues);
    return this.mMatrixValues[i];
}

public boolean contains(float f, float f2) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(-getCurrentAngle());
    float[] fArr = new float[8];
    float[] fArr2 = new float[2];
    matrix.mapPoints(fArr, getMappedBoundPoints());
    matrix.mapPoints(fArr2, new float[]{f, f2});
    return StickerUtils.trapToRect(fArr).contains(fArr2[0], fArr2[1]);
}

public abstract void draw(Canvas canvas);

public RectF getBound() {
    return new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) getWidth(), (float) getHeight());
}

public float[] getBoundPoints() {
    return !this.b ? new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, (float) getWidth(), 0.0f, 0.0f, (float) 
getHeight(), (float) getWidth(), (float) getHeight()} : new float[]{(float) getWidth(), 0.0f, 
0.0f, 0.0f, (float) getWidth(), (float) getHeight(), 0.0f, (float) getHeight()};
}

public PointF getCenterPoint() {
    return new PointF((float) (getWidth() / 2), (float) (getHeight() / 2));
}

public float getCurrentAngle() {
    return getMatrixAngle(this.a);
}

public float getCurrentHeight() {
    return getMatrixScale(this.a) * ((float) getHeight());
}

public float getCurrentScale() {
    return getMatrixScale(this.a);
}

public float getCurrentWidth() {
    return getMatrixScale(this.a) * ((float) getWidth());
}

public abstract Drawable getDrawable();

public abstract int getHeight();

public RectF getMappedBound() {
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    this.a.mapRect(rectF, getBound());
    return rectF;
}

public float[] getMappedBoundPoints() {
    float[] fArr = new float[8];
    this.a.mapPoints(fArr, getBoundPoints());
    return fArr;
}

public PointF getMappedCenterPoint() {
    PointF centerPoint = getCenterPoint();
    float[] mappedPoints = getMappedPoints(new float[]{centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y});
    return new PointF(mappedPoints[0], mappedPoints[1]);
}

public float[] getMappedPoints(float[] fArr) {
    float[] fArr2 = new float[fArr.length];
    this.a.mapPoints(fArr2, fArr);
    return fArr2;
}

public Matrix getMatrix() {
    return this.a;
}

public abstract int getWidth();

public boolean isFlipped() {
    return this.b;
}

public void release() {
}

public abstract void setDrawable(Drawable drawable);

public void setFlipped(boolean z) {
    this.b = z;
}

public void setMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    this.a.set(matrix);
}

public void setTag(String str) {
    this.tag = str;
} 
}
```

**And this is : class BitmapStickerIcon**

```
public class BitmapStickerIcon extends DrawableSticker {

     public static final float DEFAULT_ICON_EXTRA_RADIUS = 10.0f;
     public static final float DEFAULT_ICON_RADIUS = 30.0f;
     private float x;
     private float y;
     private float mIconRadius ;
     private float mIconExtraRadius ;

public BitmapStickerIcon(Drawable drwbl) {
    super(drwbl);  **//this is line #16 selected by compiler**
    this.mIconRadius = 30.0f;
    this.mIconExtraRadius = 10.0f;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawCircle(this.x, this.y, this.mIconRadius, paint);
    super.draw(canvas);
}

public float getIconExtraRadius() {
    return this.mIconExtraRadius;
}

public float getIconRadius() {
    return this.mIconRadius;
}

public float getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public float getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public void setIconExtraRadius(float f) {
    this.mIconExtraRadius = f;
}

public void setIconRadius(float f) {
    this.mIconRadius = f;
}

public void setX(float f) {
    this.x = f;
}

public void setY(float f) {
    this.y = f;
} 
}
```

**Here : class StickerView**

```
public class StickerView extends FrameLayout {

  public static final float MAX_SCALE_SIZE = 3.2f;
  public static final float MIN_SCALE_SIZE = 0.1f;
  private static final String TAG = "StickerView";
  public static float[] bitmapPoints;
  public static boolean mLocked;
  public static List<Sticker> mStickers = new ArrayList();
  private Paint mBorderPaint;
  private ActionMode mCurrentMode;
  private BitmapStickerIcon mDeleteIcon;
  private Matrix mDownMatrix;
  private float mDownX;
  private float mDownY;
  private BitmapStickerIcon mEditIcon;
  private BitmapStickerIcon mFlipIcon;
  private Sticker mHandlingSticker;
  private PointF mMidPoint;
  private Matrix mMoveMatrix;
  private float mOldDistance;
  private float mOldRotation;
  private OnStickerOperationListener mOnStickerOperationListener;
  private Matrix mSizeMatrix;
  private RectF mStickerRect;
  private int mTouchSlop;
  private BitmapStickerIcon mZoomIcon;


public static class kcm1 {


    static final int[] aaz;

    static {
        int[] iArr = new int[ActionMode.values().length];
        aaz = iArr;
        try {
            iArr[ActionMode.NONE.ordinal()] = 1;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldError unused) {
        }
        try {
            aaz[ActionMode.DRAG.ordinal()] = 2;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldError unused2) {
        }
        try {
            aaz[ActionMode.ZOOM_WITH_TWO_FINGER.ordinal()] = 3;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldError unused3) {
        }
        try {
            aaz[ActionMode.ZOOM_WITH_ICON.ordinal()] = 4;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldError unused4) {
        }
    }
}

public enum ActionMode {
    NONE,
    DRAG,
    ZOOM_WITH_TWO_FINGER,
    ZOOM_WITH_ICON,
    DELETE,
    FLIP_HORIZONTAL,
    CLICK
}


public interface OnStickerOperationListener {
    void onStickerClicked(Sticker sticker);

    void onStickerDeleted(Sticker sticker);

    void onStickerDragFinished(Sticker sticker);

    void onStickerEdit(Sticker sticker);

    void onStickerFlipped(Sticker sticker);

    void onStickerZoomFinished(Sticker sticker);
}

public StickerView(Context context) {
    this(context, null); **//this line #111 selected by compiler**
}

public StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    this(context, attributeSet, 0);
}

public StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int i) {
    super(context, attributeSet, i);
    this.mOldDistance = 0.0f;
    this.mOldRotation = 0.0f;
    this.mCurrentMode = ActionMode.NONE;
    this.mTouchSlop = 3;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    this.mBorderPaint = paint;
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.mBorderPaint.setColor(-16777216);
    this.mBorderPaint.setAlpha(128);
    this.mSizeMatrix = new Matrix();
    this.mDownMatrix = new Matrix();
    this.mMoveMatrix = new Matrix();
    this.mStickerRect = new RectF();
     **//Below line #129 the compiler select BitmapStickerIcon**
    this.mDeleteIcon = new BitmapStickerIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_close_white_18dp));
    this.mZoomIcon = new BitmapStickerIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_scale_white_18dp));
} ...more
```

I have no idea how to fix the errors, I have tested many solutions but nothing changed.
I will be happy for your help.

Comment: All we can say for certain is that `mDrawable` is `null` when you call `getIntrinsicWidth` on it. There is insufficient context to figure out where the `null` is coming from.  But I notice that at certain points you seem to be assigning `null` to that field.  The other exceptions seem to be caused by the NPE.  So solve that problem first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `StickerView` file:

1. Remove the `StickerView(Context context)` constructor
2. Put the initialization code also in the `StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)` constructor (creating a dedicated method is a good approach) and
3. Change `this(context, attributeSet, 0)` to `super(context, attributeSet)`

```
public StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    setup();
}

public StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int i) {
    super(context, attributeSet, i);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    this.mOldDistance = 0.0f;
    this.mOldRotation = 0.0f;
    this.mCurrentMode = ActionMode.NONE;
    this.mTouchSlop = 3;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    this.mBorderPaint = paint;
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.mBorderPaint.setColor(-16777216);
    this.mBorderPaint.setAlpha(128);
    this.mSizeMatrix = new Matrix();
    this.mDownMatrix = new Matrix();
    this.mMoveMatrix = new Matrix();
    this.mStickerRect = new RectF();
     **//Below line #129 the compiler select BitmapStickerIcon**
    this.mDeleteIcon = new BitmapStickerIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_close_white_18dp));
    this.mZoomIcon = new BitmapStickerIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_scale_white_18dp));
}
```